# PHP MySQL second query failing

Tags: php, mysql

Seems my second MySQL query is failing for unknown reasons. I don't get a problem when connecting, only when going to get the result from $dbLink->query();

```
$photos = getPhotos(getID($_COOKIE[$uname_cookie], $_COOKIE[$passwd_cookie]));

function getID($uName, $passwd) {
    // Just in case, for modularity :P
    include 'misc.php';
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" . $uName . "' AND Password = '" . $passwd . "';";
    $dbLink = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    if ($dbLink->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to database: " . $dbLink->connect_error;
        return null;
    } else {
        $results = $dbLink->query($query);
        print_r($results->fetch_array());
        $rows = $results->fetch_array();
        return $rows["ID"];
    }
}

function getPhotos($id) {
    // Just in case, for modularity :P
    include 'misc.php';
    $query = "SELECT Location FROM Photos WHERE UserID = " . $id . ";";
    $dbLink = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
    if ($dbLink->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to database: " . $dbLink->connect_error;
        return null;
    } else {
        $results = $dbLink->query($query);
        print_r($results->fetch_array());
        $rows = $results->fetch_array();
        return $rows["ID"];
    }
}
```

EDIT: Got it by passing around the $dbLink to the functions IE getPhotos($id, $dbLink)

Comment: You urgently need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) with `mysqli`. You should be using `bind_param`, not inserting raw user data into your query string.

Comment: No error or anything? Also, you might want to instanciate your database separately, to avoid having many different but equal connections.

Comment: @tadman I keep clicking the up arrow, but it only lets me give you one upvote!!! (jk)

Comment: @tadman I know this. I usually do this once I finish a file. Just makes it less readable for me.

Comment: There are many errors, for example for every function you are creating new database connection? the second problem is, escape variables and third problem is, do not use fetch_array if it is not important, just fetch_assoc, otherwise you are doing more loadout :]

Comment: Please, no, no, **no**. Do your escaping properly up front because you *will* forget, and if you miss even one instance, your entire application if not career can be destroyed by an [automatic injection tool](http://sqlmap.org/). Look at the features on that thing, it's terrifying. **DO NOT** commit code with injection bugs.

Comment: What do you get when you just call the getID function by itself? What does it return?

Comment: Seeing `" . $id . "` in a query should set your hair on fire. If it doesn't, you're not sufficiently scared.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT Location FROM Photos WHERE UserID = '" . $id . "';";
```